# Reserve size for vector in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I was looking for an efficient way to do this :

```
int number_of_pointcloud = 666;    
std::vector<pcl::PointCloud<PointXYZIR>> pointcloud_vector[number_of_pointcloud] ;
int size_small_pointcloud = cloud_in.size ()/ number_of_pointcloud;
for(int i = 0; i < pointcloud_vector->size (); ++i)
    pointcloud_vector[i].reserve(size_small_pointcloud);
```

Basically i want to reserve a size for each vector in my vector. Is there an elegant way of doing this ?

Comment: Are you looking for efficient or elegant? You won't get any reasonably more efficient than that. As for elegance, fixing the code formatting would be welcome, otherwise nothing to fix.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you're doing it exactly right (though I agree with Gabriel Alexander's suggestion).

Comment: You can allocate a single large vector instead of array of vectors.

Comment: Your code can't be even compiled. `pointcloud_vector->size()` is erroneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a range-for loop and shorten it considerably:

```
for(auto& e : pointcloud_vector) {
    e.reserve(size_small_pointcloud);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more short example, but it creates default elements and sized vector, NOT reserved, but sized:

```
int number_of_pointcloud = 666;    
int size_small_pointcloud = cloud_in.size ()/ number_of_pointcloud;
std::vector< std::vector<pcl::PointCloud<PointXYZIR> > > pointcloud_vector(number_of_pointcloud, std::vector<pcl::PointCloud<PointXYZIR> >(size_small_pointcloud));
```

If you accept sized vector generation then you can use this example.